# NLP modelling capabilities

Tags: nlp

I was wandering in the NLP space and have come across a peculiar situation. I had one question about NLP modelling.

Is there any model that can tell me if a person is available at any particular time?

For example, let's say I have a sentence in my test set "Mr. X was jailed in 2005 for 20 years"

And I don't have any particular training set for the model. I have a profile for Mr. X though. Now, as per the profile Mr. X is the ceo of company Y currently. Can the model now tell that the Mr. X being talked about in the test set and thenone in the profile are not the same people.

If yes, NLP can do that, what sort of data will I require, what sort of model will I require?

I am completely lost on this one. I would really appreciate any clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may research about sequence to sequence models, dialog agents and intent based models to solve this problem. I think you'll need some kind of task specific data to train the models.